# Modify user_data after stopping aws EC2 with ansible playbook(ec2 or ec2_instance module)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a EC2 instance that's already launched using ansible ec2 module having user_data(say data1). Stopped the EC2 instance, now I want to modify the user_data(say data2) and start the instance. Giving modified user_data but its not getting reflected on aws. 
To summarize, How to modify user_data of stopped aws EC2 using ansible script(with ec2 or ec2_instance) script.

Answer (score 1):

By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the boot cycle when you first launch an instance. You can update your configuration to ensure that your user data scripts and cloud-init directives run every time you restart your instance.

[User Data for every restart](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/)